# How Do i make the ping command an embed (discord bot)

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, discord, discord.js

```
    if (message.content === '-ping') {  
      message.channel.send(`Latency is : ${Date.now() - message.createdTimestamp}ms. 
API Latency is : ${Math.round(client.ws.ping)}ms`);
}
  });
```

i dont know how to make my code an embed ,how do i make this an embed?

Comment: Please look at the discord.js docs before asking a question here. All you need to do is create a [MessageEmbed](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageEmbed), and then send it with `message.channel.send()`.

Answer (score 0):

To make a basic embed, you can do:

```
if (message.content === '-ping') {
    const pingEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle("Ping")
        .setDescription(`:ping_pong: Pong!\nLatency is : ${Date.now() message.createdTimestamp}ms. 
API Latency is : ${Math.round(client.ws.ping)}ms`)
        .setColor("#03a1fc")
    message.channel.send(pingEmbed);
}
```

Just make sure at the top of the file you add `const Discord = require('discord.js');`, but if you're looking at message content for a command, chances are that's already at the top of your page. Also I'd recommend reading the [docs on embeds](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageEmbed), there are all sorts of cool methods to add images, fields, etc.